# Abort thread on new request, but complete only last request

Tags: c#, multithreading

The situation is that a certain asynchronous operation is called multiple times, which is basically to consolidate results. But I want to abort every time a new request comes in, which means that only the last call will run completely. Does this solution look reasonable?

I have tried replicating the process in a test program, where the `for` loop represents 'x' number of calls generated for consolidation. But because we only need to run calculation once, we can safely run it on the last call.

I am creating a new thread each time, and cancelling the previous ones if there are any. This seems to work, but is there a better way or can this be improved?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listCancellationTokens = new List<CancellationTokenSource>();

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        listCancellationTokens.ForEach(c => c.Cancel());

        CreateThread(cancelSource);

        listCancellationTokens.Add(cancelSource);
    }
}

private static void CreateThread(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            ConsolidateResults(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch
        {
            ;
        }
    }).Start();

}

private static void ConsolidateResults(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    UpdateValues();
    if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }
    TurnOffEvents();
    if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }
    GetMarginPercentage();

    if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }
    TurnOnEvents();
}

//This is how it is done at the moment
private void Commit(bool adjustDiscount = false)
{
    lock (_updateRunnerLock)
    {
        _updateRunnerRemainingCycles = 40;
        if (_updateRunner == null)
        {
            _updateRunner = new Thread(UpdateRunner);
            _updateRunner.Start();
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateRunner()
{
    while (_updateRunnerRemainingCycles > 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        _updateRunnerRemainingCycles--;
    }
    lock (this)
    {
        if (_updateRunner != null)
        {
            _updateRunner = null;
            ConsolidateResults();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically it is in its current state senseless to have a

```
var listCancellationTokens = new List<CancellationTokenSource>();
```

if all you want is **one** running thread at any time.

So what I suggest instead is to create **one** [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and if there comes the situation that this task should be canceled you should cancel the task and [`Wait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321315%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) until the task returned.

After the `Task` returned you then create the new `Task`.

```
private static Task task;
private static CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if(task != null && (!task.IsCompleted || !task.IsFaulted))
        {

            try 
            {
                cancelSource.Cancel();
                task.Wait(cancelSource.Token);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex) 
            { 
                //swallow because by using ThrowIfCancellationRequested() 
                //in combination with cancelSource.Cancel() an exception is thrown.
            }
        }
        cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConsolidateResults(cancelSource.Token));

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

then you should change the `ConsolidateResults()` method to

```
private static void ConsolidateResults(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    UpdateValues();
    TurnOffEvents();
    GetMarginPercentage();
    TurnOnEvents();
}
```

Comment: Why not use `Task.Run(Action, CancellationToken)` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`? (+1 though)

Comment: @RobH on this machine I have only NET 4.0 :-( the other part is I don't know what the methods in the worker method do. See the remarks here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I never knew that - very useful information! Thanks for pointing it out :)